# Fetch query with null parameter in dbaccess

Tags: ios, objective-c, dbaccess

If I'hv two dbobject like:

```
@interface Member : DBObject

@property (strong) NSString* firstname;
@property (strong) NSString* lastName;
@property (strong) Group* group;

@end

@interface Group : DBObject

@property (strong) NSString* groupName;
@property (strong) NSString* adminName;

- (DBResultSet*)members;

@end
```

In member object, I can retrieve member which relates to the group, but in member object, there are also many objects which are not contained group object. Then how can I fetch them?

I tried with this, but given empty DBResultSet.

```
[[[Member query] whereWithFormat:@"group == %@",NULL] fetch];
```

Thank in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in SQLite you cannot equate NULL, so you use a slightly different expression to work with NULL objects.  You need to use **IS NULL** or **IS NOT NULL**.

So in short, your query above would become:

```
[[[Member query] where:@"group IS NULL"] fetch];
```

It does mess up building queries with parameters sometimes, but you just have to build up your query to look a little different in that case.

For example:

```
[[[Member query] whereWithFormat:@"(group == %@ OR group IS NULL)",@(123)] fetch];
```

Thanks
Ad

Comment: Not the point here but good to know, in most of SQL db you have to use `IS` keyword to compare values with NULL.